# Unix command to add padding to lines

Tags: unix, awk, sed

Could you pls share unix command to achieve below output

Input file:

```
a1;a2;7789;1;3;4;50
b1:f7;5960;2;3;4;55;fmd
c1;f7
```

Expected:
(total 8 columns. if null value , delimiter will be added)

```
a1;a2;7789;1;3;4;50;;
b1:f7;5960;2;3;4;55;fmd;
c1;f7;;;;;;;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you start by reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please note that SO is _not_ a free coding service. We are not here to do your work for you. You are expected to program yourself and are welcome to ask here if you have any _specific questions _with the code you implemented and which you share inside your question_.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `awk`,

```
awk -F';' '{NF=9; $1=$1; print}' OFS=';' file
```

(Or)

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=";"} {NF=9; $1=$1}1' file
```

Output:

```
$ awk -F';' '{NF=9; $1=$1; print}' OFS=';' file
a1;a2;7789;1;3;4;50;;
b1:f7;5960;2;3;4;55;fmd;;
c1;f7;;;;;;;
```